# Convert last dimension of ndarray to tuple/recarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If someone could help with this, I'd be very grateful as it's been driving me a bit crazy for a couple of hours!

I have an ndarray as follows:

```
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 4]],
       [[1, 0],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 4]]])
```

I would like to convert this to a record array:

```
array([[(0, 0),
        (0, 2),
        (0, 4)],
       [(1, 0),
        (1, 2),
        (1, 4)]],
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [`.view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy-ndarray-view) to "change" the dtype and [`.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy-ndarray-reshape) to "remove" the last dimension:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([[[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 4]],
...                 [[1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 4]]])

>>> newarr = arr.view(dtype=np.dtype([('x', 'i4'), ('y', 'i4')]))
>>> newarr = newarr.reshape(newarr.shape[:-1])
>>> newarr
array([[(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 4)]], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')])
```

---

Note that you have to be careful with `.view`, hardcoding the dtype might be not "safe" here. But you can simply reuse the current dtype:

```
>>> newarr = arr.view(dtype=np.dtype([('x', arr.dtype), ('y', arr.dtype)]))
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm getting a "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged" or the reshape however. Numpy 1.11.2. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkNS When you run the code that I posted? Or in your own code?

Comment: Using exactly the code you posted: 
arr = np.array([[[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 4]], [[1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 4]]])
newarr = arr.view(dtype=np.dtype([('x', 'i4'), ('y', 'i4')]))
newarr = newarr.reshape(newarr.shape[:-1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Users/markns/miniconda3/envs/alder/lib/python3.5/site-...
  File "<ipython-input-235-e8134bfc6b99>", line 1, in <module>
    newarr = newarr.reshape(newarr.shape[:-1])
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: could you try it with the `newarr = arr.view(dtype=np.dtype([('x', arr.dtype), ('y', arr.dtype)]))` instead of `newarr = arr.view(dtype=np.dtype([('x', 'i4'), ('y', 'i4')]))`?

Comment: That need squeeze out that last dimension bugs me. And you have to add one back in when going the other direction.  Sometimes I've recommended a `tolist` intermediary, http://stackoverflow.com/a/43396313/901925, especially when going from structured to regular.

Comment: @hpaulj the reshaping or squeeze might be a nuisance, but at least it's a very cheap operation - `tolist` isn't even if it's definetly "shorter".

Comment: `squeeze(axis=-1)` is a little shorter

Comment: viewing to and from `np.complex` has the same issue.  A singular dimension is retained.  Some sort of logic may require it, but it still feels like a rough edge.