# How to zip 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-zip

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

I've 2 identical 2D arrays, I'm trying to zip them element-wise. It should look like:

```
[[(1,1) (2,2), (3,3)]
[(4,4) (5,5) (6,6)]
[(7,7) (8,8) (9,9)]]
```

I've tried the method below but it didn't work out. First flatten the arrays, zip them, convert it into a list, then convert it into an array and reshape it.

```
np.array(list(zip(np.ndarray.flatten(a),np.ndarray.flatten(b)))).reshape(a.shape)
```

I'm getting the following error

```
cannot reshape array of size 18 into shape (3,3)
```

It's not treating the elements `(1,1) (2,2)` etc. of the final array as tuples but as individual elements. Hence, 18 elements.

This question has been posted once but I didn't find an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17960617/17820006) that worked for me.

Comment: An `ndarray` of tuples isn't going to be more useful than an equivalent linked list.  `numpy` is for doing math, and you can't math tuples without unraveling them natively (complex number formats notwithstanding).  Do you instead want an array with a final dimension of `2`?

Comment: @DanielF Ideally yes. But I can manage with a 3D array too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `zip`, use numpy native functions! You want a [`dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
out = np.dstack([a, b])
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [5, 5],
        [6, 6]],

       [[7, 7],
        [8, 8],
        [9, 9]]])
```

Comment: ```np.dstack([a,b)``` gives me a 3D array. I can manage with this but just for the sake of convinience, can array elements be stored as tuples, i.e. I want element of the form (1,1), with array shape (3,3)? @mozway

Comment: Storing as tuples would implicate that you have to use an `object` dtypes, meaning that you won't benefit from most of the vectorized operations. If you really need to do this, use [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426039/convert-last-dimension-of-ndarray-to-tuple-recarray).

Comment: Got it, for me there's no point in having it in form of tuples then @mozway